# changing the arrangement of a file

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file as shown below

```
>1BA9
394
395
396
397    
>1CA3
438
439
440
441
442
```

I would like to arrange the above file like this

```
1BA9  394  397
1CA3  438  442
```

How is it possible with awk or sed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -v RS='>' 'NR>1{print $1, $2, $NF}' file
```

- Change the default Record Separator.
- Print first, second and last fields.
- Since your line starts with the separator use `NR>1` to skip first empty record.

Comment: Specifying `\n` as FS explicitly means you want `$(NF-1)` to account for the last empty field, better just `awk 'NR>1{print $1,$2,$NF}' RS='>' file`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^>/!{H;$!d};x;s/\n\([^\n]*\)\n.*\n/ \1 /p;x;h;d' file
```

This stores the multiline sequence from any line beginning with `>` to the next such sequence or end-of-file in the hold space. Then removes the unwanted parts and prints out the result.